# Need to match string to line in file in Python

Tags: python, file, list, format, abbreviation

my first time asking something here. I have a text file of names, 1 name per line, that i'm reading in to a list, and then duplicating that list twice, the first time to remove \n's and a second time to lowercase the list. then I ask the user for a search term, and convert their input to lowercase, and then search the lowercase version of the list for that, then i get the index of the match, and use that to display the non-lowercase version of that list item back to the user (so they can type for example anivia and get back Anivia). This is working fine but I'm sure my code is pretty bad. What I would like to do is add specific abreviations for some of the names in the list file, and accept those abbreviations as input, but still display back the full name. For example, user enters "mumu" and it sees that the list has Amumu - mumu, to reference Amumu. How could I go about accepting that abreviation? Also other cases like mf for Miss Fortune or kha for Kha'Zix. I thought of maybe having a second file contain the list of abbreviations but that seems so wasteful and I'm sure theres a better way. Here is my bad code so far:

```
f = open("champions.txt") #open the file
list = f.readlines() #load each line into the list
#print list
list2 = [item.rstrip('\n') for item in list] #remove trailing newlines in copy list
list3 = [item.lower() for item in list2] #make it all lowercase

print "-------\n", list2 #print the list with no newlines just to check

print "which champ" #ask user for input
value = raw_input().lower() #get the input and make it lowercase
if value in list3: #check list for value and then print back a message using that index but from the non-lowercase list
    pos = list3.index(value)
    print "list contains", list2[pos]
else: #if the input doesn't match an item print an error message
    print "error"
```

ill put this all into some function in my main file once it's working the way i need. Basically I want to change some of the lines in my text file to have valid alternate abreviations and be able to accept those in this and still display the full name back to the user. For example, one of the lines in my secondary text file that has the abbreviations has a line of:

```
Kog'Maw - kogmaw, kog, km
```

how can i simplify what I have and add that functionality? I'm not really sure where to start, I'm pretty new to python and programming in general. Thank you for any help you can provide, sorry for such a long post.

Comment: you shouldn't call a variable `list`; it is the name of a python builtin.

Comment: You mention a secondary text file. When is it created and what is in it?

Comment: @martineau i made them myself, they look something like this: [link]http://www.pasteall.org/37416

Comment: OK, thanks. I think you should just have one file that includes any abbreviations that exist. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's a revised answer that assumes there's one file containing names and abbreviations as shown at the beginning of [this](http://www.pasteall.org/37416).

Essentially what it does is make a large lookup table that maps any abbreviation in the file plus the name itself in lowercase to the name at the beginning of each line.

```
lookup = {}
with open("champions.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().split('-', 1)
        if not line: continue # skip any blank lines

        name = line[0].strip()
        lookup[name.lower()] = name
        if len(line) == 2:  # any alternative names given?
            for item in line[1].split(','):
                lookup[item.strip()] = name

print 'lookup table:'
for alt_name, real_name in sorted(lookup.items()):
    print '{}: {}'.format(alt_name, real_name)
print

while True:
    print "which champ (Enter to quit): "  # ask user for input
    value = raw_input().lower()  # get the input and make it lowercase
    if not value: break

    real_name = lookup.get(value)
    if real_name:
        print 'found:', value, '-->', real_name
    else:
        print 'error: no match for', value
```

Comment: I want my name list file (champions.txt) to have valid abbreviations on the lines of the names, and i want to be able to print the full name back to the user even if they input the abbreviation or have different casing (Lux vs lux). My project has another file to write statss to that the user inputs for each name, so i need to be able to accept abbreviations so it's quicker and more natural.

Comment: thank you @martineau I'll give that a try and see how it works, also thank you for the comments it helps me understand it better

Comment: i've gotten around to trying out your version there but it doesn't seem to be running, i'm  getting a valueerror: PS C:\Users\Kassandra\pystuff> python helptest1.py
lookup table:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helptest1.py", line 15, in <module>
    print '{}: {}'.format(alt_name, real_name)
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: a bit of an update, i found other people having similar errors and it seems to be python version related, i am running 2.6.5 for this (and the book tutorial i've been learning with also uses a pre-3 version), apparently in py2.7 and 3 this is not a problem, it relates to a number in the brackets being omitted, i will try another python version and see if i still have trouble

Comment: I'm using 2.7.3. Changing it to an old-style `'%s: %s' % (alt_name, real_name)` should make it work in all versions.

Comment: after some fussing attempting to fix environment path to no avail i decided to uninstall py26 and py27 and reinstall them, and set py27 as the default one when installing, now it works :) i need 26 still for older versions of Blender but for now this is working fine, ill also try that old style line you have there (that sort of thing is seen alot more in the book/tutorial ive been following: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ I think this does exactly what I want now I just have to adapt it to work with my main  menu file so I can just call it all as a function. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use useful names. So, instead of `list2` call it `lower_names`, etc.

Second, you could replace the `in` operator and `index` call by just one `index` call. If you noticed, a call to `some_list.index(item_which_does_not_exist)` will raise a `valueError` saying that the item is not in the list. The most "pythonic" way to do this is by `try`ing to get the index, `except` if it fails, then you would do something else.

So you could replace the `if` part by this:

```
try:
    pos = list3.index(value)
except ValueError:
    print 'error'
else:
    print 'everything is ok. there was no exception raised'
    print 'list contains', list2[pos]
```

It is often said in the python philosophy that it is better to ask for forgiveness than for permission. :)

Another important thing, and this is only assuming that you want to match a lowercase name to its "real" name, you need here a dictionary. A dictionary maps a key to a value, so what you have here is a case where you want each lowercase name (key) to map to the real name (value). It can be defined this way (I see you are familiar with one liners):

```
name_map = {item.lower(): item for item in (line.strip() for line in f)}
```

So, instead of using `readlines`, you can directly loop through the file. That's extra sugar in Python.

And then, you can do something like: `value in name_map` or `real_name = name_map[value]`.

As for the extra functionality, I'd go for your second option, which is `name - nickname1,nickname2`. So what you need to do is: read each line, split by the dash `-` (or whatever other character that will not be used in the names), then split the second part by the commas to have each name alone. Wrapping up:

```
name_map = {}
nick_map = {}
for line in f:
    parts = line.strip().split('-')
    name = parts[0].strip()
    nicks = {n.strip(): name for n in parts[1].split(',')}
    name_map[name.lower()] = name
    nick_map.update(nicks)

# To check a name:
if value in name_map:
   # Exact match
elif value in nick_map:
   # Nickname match
else:
   # No Match
```

You could do the equivalent with try/except/else clauses, but that will make too much nesting, which is not recommended.

Comment: This looks promising but how do I deal with loading the name list file into the name_map and nick_map? especially with only some specific names having abbreviations

Comment: This is what the first loop does, read from the file and fill the dictionaries. martineau's answer goes deeper in the details and deals with all these cases.